# Initializing variables inside templates

Tags: c++, templates

My program is supposed to add the numbers if integers or doubles are passed to the function or concatenate them if they are strings.

```
template<class T>
T add(vector<T> v)
{
  T temp;
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    temp += v[i];
  }
  return temp;
}
```

If I leave the temp uninitialized it won't add the elements in the vector of the integers I pass to it, but if I initialize it to 0, it won't concatenate the vector elements in the vector of strings.

How should I initialize the `temp` variable?

Comment: `T temp{};` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `temp` to the first element and iterate over the remaining elements:

```c++
template<class T>
T add(vector<T> v)
{
  T temp = v[0];
  for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    temp += v[i];
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Should probably include a test that the vector is non-empty as well. (Or at least a precondition.)

Answer (score 0):

Use an algorithm

```
template<class T>
T add(std::vector<T> const & v)
{
  return std::accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), T{}, std::plus{});
}
```

This will take care of the empty vector case as well.

Also, take the input vector by const reference.

Note that pre-c++17, you have to say `std::plus<T>{}`.